# Views contextual filters by node title

Tags: nodes, views

I've created a content type: **seller** and with pathauto module I've set this content type to be **seller/[node:title]** so every new seller content will be **www.example.com/seller/[name_of_the_seller].**

I want to add gmap objects in every seller page with only their objects will be visible. (for this detail I'll open a new thread, 'cos I'm not sure how to filter that)

With Views module I've added a page with url:  **/seller/%**

and in contextual filters I've added **Content: Nid**.
In **When the filter value is NOT in the URL** I've selected **Provide default value** and in the field bellow I've put **seller**.
That didn't worked, so I've tried with **Raw value from URL** and checked **Use path alias**.
That didn't worked too. I've searched couple of other threads, but I didn't find like my problem.

UPDATE

I've solved the problem by creating a block that is displayed seller/*. The two content types has a same taxonomy terms and with contextual filters  **Content: Has taxonomy term ID**, **Provide default value**, **Taxonomy term ID from URL**, I've marked **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks** and **Limit terms by vocabulary** and I've selected the **seller** taxonomy.

Comment: Could you please explain in real world terms what you are trying to acomplish. I think you are misunderstanding how a contextual filter works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by creating a block that is displayed seller/*. The two content types has a same taxonomy terms and with contextual filters  **Content: Has taxonomy term ID**, **Provide default value**, **Taxonomy term ID from URL**, I've marked **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks** and **Limit terms by vocabulary** and I've selected the **seller** taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

Since your contextual filter is expecting an **nid** (you said your contextual filter is set up as '**Content: Nid**') - you really have to provide it with an nid even when that filter is not present in the URL.  You can't give it 'seller' as an argument or anything like that because that's not an nid, so it won't help it pull up the correct node.

So to get it to work in those cases, what you really want for your view to do is grab the nid of the current node it appears on.  It's OK if that page has a custom URL, the nid can still be gotten.

Just select '**Content ID from URL**' as the default value when an URL argument doesn't exist!  That'll work even if it has a custom alias for the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Boriana. I've tried that too before, but it didn't worked. In my view page the path is **seller/%** and Configure contextual filter: **Content: Nid** with option **Provide default value/Content ID from URL.**  Is that correct, or I'm missing something?

Comment: I feel like I'm going in wrong direction. My idea is to display gmaps in every seller page with only objects created by the user. I've managed to do that in their user page like this: a views page with path: **user/%** and contextual filters **Content: Author uid / Provide default value: User ID from logged in user**. In their user page there is a gmap with object created from user and is working great. Is this possible to do in every sellers page? I know it's difficult to explain well, but if you some suggestion, I'll try to add more details about my idea.

Comment: Perhaps one easy way to do that would be if you include the seller's uid in the custom path you've made for the seller's pages.  Then you can use the 'Raw value from URL' and specify to use the 2nd, 3rd or whatever path portion the uid is embedded in.  Then the view will use the correct uid when you place it on a seller's page.  Would that work?